# XSLT Filter nodes multiple conditions

Tags: xslt

I am looking for a way to filter out some nodes in an XML. In output I would like to leave all nodes **if**:

`<year>` is 2020

**and**

`<year>` is 2019 **AND** `<available>` is YES.

**raw xml:**

```
<root>
    <item>
        <code>1</code>
        <available>YES</available>
        <year>2020</year>
    </item>
    <item>
        <code>2</code>
        <available>NO</available>
        <year>2020</year>
    </item>
    <item>
        <code>3</code>
        <available>NO</available>
        <year>2019</year>
    </item>
    <item>
        <code>3</code>
        <available>YES</available>
        <year>2019</year>
    </item>
</root>
```

**Test output:**

```
<root>
    <item>
        <code>1</code>
        <available>YES</available>
        <year>2020</year>
    </item>
    <item>
        <code>2</code>
        <available>NO</available>
        <year>2020</year>
    </item>
    <item>
        <code>3</code>
        <available>YES</available>
        <year>2019</year>
    </item>
</root>
```

I can filter out 2020, 2019 nodes with:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item[not(YEAR = 2020) and not(YEAR = 2019)]" />

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I just can't refine the second condition `<year> is 2019 AND <available> is YES.`

Comment: XML is case-sensitive: `YEAR` is not the same thing as `year`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `year` cannot be `2020` **AND** `2019`. I believe you meant:

> `year` is `2020`
>   **OR**
>   `year` is `2019` **AND** `available` is `YES`

Formulating this as:

```
<xsl:template match="item[not(year=2020 or year=2019 and available='YES')]" />
```

will produce the requested result.